# Which part of speech is "left" in "now there are only 5 cars left"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, participles, parsing

I've always thought (perhaps, erroneously) that if there is some ambiguity in determining whether the given word is an adjective or a past participle, you need to look at whether the "source" of action is mentioned in the sentence. If the source is not mentioned, then it is an adjective. For example:

> The **disappointed** boy was sitting on a bench.

Here, we don't know the source of the boy's disappointment, in other words, we don't know who performed the action of letting the boy down, Therefore, **disappointed** is an adjective.

But when the source is mentioned, then it is a past participle. For example:

> The boy was greatly **disappointed** *by his mom*.

Here, we know the "source" - the boy's mom - therefore, **disappointed** is a past participle here.

However, this method doesn't seem to work in the following sentence:

> One car drove away 10 minutes ago. Two more cars drove away 5 minutes
>   ago. So now there are only 5 cars **left** in the parking lot.

Firstly, I thought that, since the source is not mentioned, it was either an adjective or an adverb, but the [*Wiktionary page doesn't reserve this meaning for the adjective "**left**" or for the adverb "**left**"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/left#Adverb). It reserves that meaning only for the past participle "**left**", which is one of the forms of the verb "**leave**". So, most likely the word "**left**" in this sentence is a past participle.

However, the "source of leaving" is not mentioned in the sentence and it is not even implied, which means that the method that I've been using was wrong. But then I am really at loss in how to differentiate between adjectives and past participles.

Comment: *Only five apples had been left on the plate.* Do you think *left* is possibly an adjective there?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - "Do you think left is possibly an adjective there?" - Yes, I thought it was an adjective because the agent was not mentioned in the sentence.

Comment: As a native speaker, I understand **had been left** to refer to a past act of placing the apples on the plate, whereas **were left** to refer *either* to a past act of placing the apples on the plate or to the current state of the apples, that is, they are "remaining". The copula **were** with past participle is ambiguous to me in a way that **had been left** is not.  I do not think that is an idiosyncratic understanding on my part;  I think it would be shared by most native speakers.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - That's, actually, the reason why I changed my example from apples to cars. While it's clear that somebody was taking apples and leaving them - that is, performing the action of leaving on apples - it is not the case with cars - the cars were leaving by themselves. To make that even clearer we can change cars to some animals, say, raccoons.

Comment: It is still ambiguous with the copula. *Three people were left in the room.* could mean "Three people had not departed yet"  and thus **left** refers to their state of remaining, or it could mean something like "Three people had not been fetched from the room" (perhaps by a nurse who was showing patients in to an examination room and had forgotten to show them in).  But *Three people had been left in the room* is clearly a case of them not having been fetched from the room.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I see. Thank you. So, do you think we could sum it up like "it all depends on the implied meaning" then? That is, if it's a case of people merely remaining, then "left" is an adjective; and if it's the case of someone else performing some action on them - like the nurse's act of fetching them in your example - than "left" is a past participle?

Comment: Yes, you have to assess the predication.  *There were three apples left.*  With that existential construction, "There were", the past participle **left** refers to the existential state of the apples, and that is usually labeled "adjectival".  *Three apples are left.*    Again, their existential state is referred to.  *Three apples had been left* would refer to an *act* that resulted in them being there, and there **left** is a perfective verbal.  The perfective with transitive verbs and the state the perfective entails are flip sides of the same coin.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - WOW! Sounds a bit too scientific to me, but I did get the main point! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Left" is an adjective in your example, with the meaning "remain". It has a stative meaning, not a dynamic one, and hence this is not a verbal passive, but an adjectival one.

Comment: Replacement of "be" by "remain" serves to remove the ambiguity in favour of an adjectival reading: "There remained only 5 cars  in the parking lot".

Comment: I think @BillJ is addressing **were left on the table** not **had been left on the table**. The question has been edited to talk about "cars were left in the lot" (the apples are gone) but it's the same, **cars were left in the lot** vs **cars had been left in the lot**.  With **were**  the word **left** can be a stative adjective or a passive, but with **had been** the word left is not adjectival. Also, a complement can change your view of things:  *The apples were left to rot*.  There, **left** means "abandoned". It's not a pure adjective. The rule of thumb is not air-tight.

Comment: @Lambie.  The question originally had apples on plate not cars in a lot, and it was about a rule of thumb the OP had developed for slapping labels on the word **left**.  I don't think there's any "bad faith" just a mutating question where small changes can make a major difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### TL;DR

Depending on how the sentence is parsed, "left" can apparently be considered a verb, an adverb, or even a preposition. (I can't fully explain the latter, but perhaps a generative grammar person can chime in).

###### Ambiguity in parts of speech

Parts of speech can be tricky in that they can depend on how a sentence is parsed. One problem with theories of linguistics, in fact, is that they can't always fully account for things that are left out of some utterances (yet presumed by the speaker and/or addressee), but which can influence how an utterance is perceived and parsed. This sentence is a good example, since

> So now there are only 5 cars left in the parking lot.

could be understood *somewhat* differently depending on it is broken up, where the main ambiguity is whether "left" is part of a subordinate clause describing the five cars, or whether "in the parking lot" is where the cars have been left (by some unknown/presumed agent(s)):

> ...there are only 5 cars {[that have] left in the parking lot}.
> ...only 5 cars are left {in the parking lot}.
> ...5 cars {remain} {in the parking lot}  (note "remain" is a linking/copular verb)

These different ways of parsing the phrase might seem like splitting hairs (and in practice they're almost entirely irrelevant), but which one of these or other interpretations one starts with can make a difference as to what part of speech "left" can be analyzed as.

###### Some sentence trees

So while at first glance this seems like a fairly simple question, plugging the example sentence into an online [Linguistics Tree Solver](https://adambcomer.com/lin-tree-solver/) didn't immediately offer a easy or even a single way to parse it. In fact, there were so many possible permutations I lost track of them, but below are some.*

I started out inserting "that were" before "left" because it seemed like that would make it obvious there was a hidden subordinate clause containing "left in the parking lot", but the Tree Solver didn't see it that way:

[image: sentence tree with "that were" inserted]

Using the original sentence and specifying "left" as a verb, as suggested by the tree above, generated this tree, which was unsatisfying because "left in the parking lot" didn't feel like its own, separate verb phrase in my interpretation:

[image: left in parking lot as separate verb phrase]

If "left" was specified as an adverb, the tree was closer to what I would originally have expected, with "only 5...in the parking lot" as a single verb phrase:

[image: single verb phrase]

However, this still wasn't entirely satisfying so I attempted some other possible combinations. The Linguistics Tree Solver will attempt to make trees based on three different sets of [syntax rules](https://adambcomer.com/lin-tree-solver/rules). Here's the same tree as above drawn using X-Bar Theory, a more complex set of syntax rules:

[image: single verb phrase x-bar]

In addition to generating trees with "left" as a verb or adverb, The X-Bar Theory syntax generated a tree in which "left" was a preposition—and even appeared to prefer that among the three possibilities.†

[image]

It seems counterintuitive that "left" could be a preposition (P) in a prepositional phrase (PP) without a noun before which it is "pre-positioned," but perhaps that's because of the pernicious idea that a preposition *must always* come before something (e.g. that prepositions shouldn't end sentences, which is a fallacy we should disabuse ourselves of).

##### Note of clarification

A final note on the "PP" notation in the last tree, which is short for "prepositional phrase"—not to be confused with "past participle." I mention this because, as your question notes, "left" *is* the past participle of "leave." And while [one answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/196565/133553) notes that you're right about that, I don't think that answer is precisely correct that a participle (past or otherwise) is a "part of speech". Rather a participle is one *form* of a specific part of speech, the verb, albeit a confusing one since it can function as *other* parts of speech, all the while not being a part of speech itself. Some supporting evidence:

In English a participle generally "[can function independently *as an adjective*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/participle)" (my emphasis). And a [past participle](https://www.wordnik.com/words/past%20participle) specifically is

> a verb form...that is used *as a verbal adjective* in phrases such as "finished work" and "baked beans" and with auxiliaries [where it remains a verb] to form the passive voice or perfect and pluperfect tenses in constructions such as "The work was finished" and "She had baked the beans". [my emphasis and add'l punctuation]

---

<sup>*The Linguistics Tree Solver tool requires the user to specify the (possible) part(s) of speech for each word in order to construct the tree, so while I attempted to try all possible permutations in order to get it to recognize the grammar of the sentence, it's possible I missed some and that there are additional ways to parse this sentence.</sup>

<sup>†By "prefer" I mean that if verb, adverb, and preposition were all selected as possible parts of speech for "leave", the tree was generated with "leave" as a preposition.</sup>

Comment: WOW! This is just amazing! Thank you.

Comment: @brilliant Strangely enough, I hadn't noticed until literally just now that this question was posed nearly four years before I attempted an answer...but glad to know it may still have been helpful, if not timely ;)

Comment: It happens here :)

Answer (score 0):

> So now there are only 5 cars left in the parking lot.

can be "simplified" to:

> Cars **are left** in the parking lot.

So you are correct when saying that in this case, 'left' is a participle.

As it is usual with passive voice, the actor who performed the action is not mentioned:

> The ceiling is painted.

Which can be extended to:

> The ceiling was painted by Michelangelo.

Comment: (1) **"As it is usual with passive voice, the actor who performed the action is not mentioned"** - The problem is the actor is not only not mentioned, but he is not even implied and even cannot possibly exist. I think the right way to go about it is to see whether the existential meaning is being conveyed (in which case it's an adjective) or not (in which case it's a past participle).

Comment: (2) Consider this case: _"In the whole world there were only 6 people who had this particular phenomenon. Sadly, we heard that one of them was killed yesterday by a burglar. So now there are only 5 such persons left."_ - The burglar here knew nothing about the person he was killing. It's not like the burglar had a goal to kill all six people that had that particular phenomenon. So you can't possibly say that the burglar "left" the other five alive. He doesn't even know anything about those five. So, in this case "left" is definitely an adjective, not participle.

Comment: @brilliant: your points are very interesting. Actors exist many times, even if they are not known. Somebody must have driven the cars there before **leaving**. When you refer to "existential meaning", I understand philosophy rather than grammar. And passive voice does not include a meaning of intent. You are right, the robber did not plan to "leave" 5 people, he merely robbed (and killed) one. But as overall picture, 6 people existed, and 5 people are left.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89769/discussion-on-answer-by-virolino-which-part-of-speech-is-left-in-this-sentence).

Comment: "One car drove away. Now there are only five cars parked." Here "parked" is a participle. You can also use a present participle: "Now there are only five cars waiting".

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to phrase this sentence would actually be as follows

> One car drove away 10 minutes ago. Two more cars drove away 5 minutes
> ago. So now only 5 cars remain in the parking lot.

Using "There are only 5 cars left" means that someone or something took the others (*leaving* the rest), and in this sentence no person is actually mentioned. Presumably, these could be self-driving cars, since they are described as having driven away, not having *been* driven away; they are acting, not being acted upon. For this reason, they continue to act in the final sentence; only 5 cars *remain*.

Comment: (1) I think it's absolutely correct to say in this case : "There are only 5 cars left". Consider this sentence: "After Giant Softshell Turtle dies, only three are left on Earth" ( https://twitter.com/NoExtinctions/status/717019790980808706 ).The act of dying is committed by turtles themselves, in other words, they act; however, the sentence says "are left" instead of "remain".

Comment: (2) Besides, the whole example in my question could have been written in the way of "having been driven away" and then the final sentence would have been absolutely okay: "One car was driven away 10 minutes ago. Two more cars were driven away 5 minutes ago. So now there are only 5 cars left in the parking lot."

Comment: (1) You are free to think as you wish. Not every single rule of English is written in a book or on the internet, so the only source I have for this is logical reasoning and personal debates among my peers. The fact remains that "to leave" has to be done by someone or something, and that "left" is always (except when opposite of "right" or used in politics) the past-tense form of "leave". Your turtle example, I would argue, is therefore not perfectly correct.

Comment: (2) Sure, you could change the sentence, and then "left" would be absolutely okay. But without changing the sentence, leaving it as it is, it is not _as_ correct (though it would still be quite acceptable by most people). As stated in my above comment, this is not a rule which is taught from textbooks, yet has (as is apparent) caused questions to arise as to the proper use or classification of the word(s).

Comment: (1) I understand your points. "...and that "left" is always (except when opposite of "right" or used in politics) the past-tense form of "leave""
- Are you sure about it? Consider this example: "_Until before yesterday there were five of these special trademark multicolored pencils in our house. Sadly, my two-year old son broke one of them yesterday, so now there are only four of them left._" Would you insist that a toddler had an original intention of breaking all pencils, but then had a second thought, had "some mercy" on the other four and, thus, left them to be?

Comment: (2) I would even doubt the notion that saying "now only four pencils remain" is more suitable in this case than "now there are only four pencils left".

Comment: (1) I haven't stated at any point that it has to do with intent; I would even say that it has nothing to do with intent, and only to do with an active vs passive verb. The toddler did leave them unbroken, whether he intended to or not. For instance, if you set down a pile of books and then hurriedly picked them back up and walked away, but you accidentally left one behind, it does not mean you _intended_ to leave a book, simply that you did, indeed, _leave_ a book; there was one book left on the ground. Intent plays no part in whether a verb is active or passive.

Comment: (1) There might have been no intent, but, at the very least, the object was exposed to the actor's action, that is, the actor's action was directed at the object. Like in your example with books, my action of picking up was directed at some point at the book, except in case with that book the action was not carried out successfully.

Comment: (2) Besides, when someone leaves something, at the very least he or she firstly has that something in his/her possession before leaving that something. However, the other four pencils in my example might have not been anywhere near the toddler. They might have been in some other room and the toddler might have not even known of their existence. Thus, the action of breaking was not directed at them at all.

Comment: (3) You may consider another example: "The hurricane killed the only authentic Sequoya tree in Asia yesterday. So now only five genuine Sequoya trees are left in this world, and they are all in the USA." Those trees in the USA have never been exposed to that hurricane that took place in Asia. That hurricane has never been directed at them. There was simply not a slightest case of interaction between that hurricane and those trees, and those trees have never been in that hurricane's possession. Same with the four pencils and the toddler.

Comment: To minimize comments, I will explain my reasoning. 

"Leave" is an active verb performed by a subject; an object is always required, but is often omitted and instead assumed (if you leave a party, you can simply say "I left."). So if any thing is ever left, it implies that _something_ performed the action of leaving that thing. If there is no subject which could have performed the leaving action, then "left" is the incorrect word to use and the object, instead, is the subject. This is why "only (qty) of subject _remains_" is a better, more precise sentence.

Comment: Well, I see where you are coming from, but I think this is a rule, which you are creating for yourself. In most cases, it is a correct one, but, perhaps, you need something more substantial than that before you can claim that saying "Now we only have four such pencils left" is less natural than saying "Now only four such pencils remain in our possession"

Comment: @brilliant I can concede that it is certainly more natural to use "Now we only have four such pencils left" than to say "Now only four such pencils remain in our possession". But I have to insist that this is not a personal rule and is really just using the language as it is defined... not all natural conversation is actually correct. As a matter of fact, much of it is not and it is why English is one of the most difficult languages to learn. But if we are aiming for most natural, then I am happy to remove my answer.

Comment: There is no need to remove your reply. Your reply is a great input into the subject matter and may be useful for those who will land on this page in the future. It is just that since you insist that this is not a personal rule and is really just using the language as it is defined and, besides, it is also a convention on this website to provide answers with authoritative sources, it would be good if you added some link to that rule in your reply.

Answer (score -1):

In my point of view. There are 3 kinds of adjectives.

(1) Comparable Adjective (the original adjectives) {e.g. big, clean}

(2) Modifier Noun (any noun can be used as adjective) {e.g. **chicken** burger, **crocodile** bag}

(3) Modifier Participle (Past Participle and Present Participle) {e.g. a **closed** shop, a **closing** shop}.

So, the answer to your question is "left" is an adjective as Word Class in your sentence because there is no participle in Nine Word Classes.

And you don't need to differentiate between adjectives and past participles because participles can be used as adjectives.

Comment: What is "Word Class", and what are you referring to with "Nine Word Classes"?

Comment: English words are divided into nine word classes according to their grammar. (1)adjective (2)adverb (3)conjunction (4)determiner (5)exclamation (6)noun (7)preposition (8)pronoun (9)verb.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a link to those Nine Word Classes?

Comment: Sorry, I copy them from my notes. I don't remember where I got it from. "Word Classes" are also called "Parts of Speech".

Comment: How many "kinds" of adjectives there are in English (if adjectives are even divided up in such a way) is not really a matter of point of view. There might be a debate about how many/what kinds there are, but that's not quite the same as it being a matter of opinion or perspective.

Comment: Also the examples you give in (2) and the second one in (3) [aren't adjectives, despite their being modifiers](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/noun-modifiers). **Chicken** and **crocodile** are still nouns, and **closing** is still a gerund ([a type of noun](https://www.wordnik.com/words/gerund)).

Comment: First, I'm not an English Professor nor Native Speaker. I'm just an English Learner. I'm just sharing how I see with you all. Someone asked me a reference and I cannot provide that. My knowledge is limited. Even if a book said something, that doesn't mean it's true. Books are dead. We, people and thinking of people are alive. At least that's how I see.

Comment: As I mentioned above "words are divided according to their grammar" i.e. " how they work". If we use "closing" as Present Participle, it is a verb. If we use it as Gerund, it is a Noun. If we use it as Modifier, it is an adjective. Otherwise, there will be Gerund as a word class and we won't call a Gerund as "a type of Noun".

Comment: What do adjectives do? They describe nouns. If we say "a bottle of water", both "bottle" and "water" are Nouns. If we say "water bottle", it means "a bottle used to store water". The word "water" describes "bottle". So it is an adjective. "chicken burger = a burger that is made with chicken". Chicken is an adjective. "crocodile bag = a bag that is made from crocodile skin". Crocodile is an adjective, despite the fact that OALD shows it as Uncountable Noun.