# How many tickets do you have left? (the modification of 'left')

Tags: parts-of-speech, past-participles

> How many tickets do you have left?

> How many tickets do you have?

What is the parts of speech of 'left' and what does the 'left' modify?

Answer (score 1):

It's an adjective derived from a past participle, and it is functioning as an adjunct to *have* (compare *How many tickets do you have in the box?*)

Comment: Can I say: How many tickets left do you have?

Comment: That doesn't sound idiomatic. If don't think _left_ modifies _tickets_.

Comment: A case could be made for it being an optional PC of "have". Compare the declarative "I have two tickets left", where "left" is an adjective functioning as subjective PC of "have" with "tickets" as predicand.

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184377/which-part-of-speech-is-left-in-now-there-are-only-5-cars-left?rq=1).

Comment: @ColinFine Can I say: How many tickets do you have left at home?

Comment: @BEBYGONES: yes _How many tickets do you have left at home?_ is fine.

Comment: @ColinFine Your answer is short but clear. I admire it.